# reliably update git working copy

Tags: git, repository

i couldnt find fitting answers for my usecase, so i hope someone has done this before and has a solution.

i intend to use git to deploy changes to an aws instance. for example i use the master branch for production. i thought i had figured out a solution that would work in any case, which is the following:

```
git fetch
git checkout -f origin/<branchname>
git pull origin <branchname>
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

i thought this would handle detached head state properly. and it seemingly worked for a while, but with recent updates, it just checks out the local branch and doesnt pull changed from remote.

so basic requirements would be:
fix/work around detached head state
update/add new submodules

here is most of the output from running above steps in terminal on the repo

```
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 22, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Total 22 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (22/22), done.
From redacted:redacteduser/redactedrepo
   b1cceb5..ee34124  master     -> origin/master
   08ec66e..ee34124  development -> origin/development
Fetching submodule redacted/redactedsubmodule
remote: Counting objects: 34, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 34 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (34/34), done.
From redacted:redacteduser/redactedsubrepo
   4d52d03..7019d5a  master     -> origin/master
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git checkout -f origin/master
Note: checking out 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at ee34124... redactedcommitmessage
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git pull origin master
From redacted:redacteduser/redactedrepo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule path 'redacted/redactedsubmodule': checked out '7019d5a442cc5f69e99f3434de23a646c563589a'
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git submodule update --recursive --remote
<no output from this command>
```

nothing points to the fact that it hasnt updated the new commits on the master branch. i then ran some more stuff as seen here

```
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git status
HEAD detached at origin/master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git checkout master
M       redacted/redactedsubmodule
Previous HEAD position was ee34124... redactedcommitmessage
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
redacteduser@ip-redacted:/redacted$ git pull
Updating b1cceb5..ee34124
Fast-forward
 redactedlistoffiles
 7 files changed, 94 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 redactedfile1
 create mode 100644 redactedfile2
```

so the repo still was 5 commits behind, even though i used fetch,checkout and pull on said branch. do i just have to reorder my commands or execute them twice in a row? i hope someone knows an answer

thanks in advance

Comment: why do you work on a detached head ?
git fetch
git checkout <branchname>
git pull origin <branchname>

Comment: i dont know why its sometimes detached. its now in attached state, and i hope it stays that way. but i still want to be ready for the case that it landed in detached again. do your steps attach the head again?

Comment: it's detached because you give git a place that is on remote:
not : git checkout -f origin/<branchname> ,  but git checkout <branchname>, no o-f nor origin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a detached head, you don't need to:

`git fetch

 git checkout <branchname>

 git pull origin <branchname>`

remove the "-f origin/" from your checkout command